# How to sync the time of a java application running on docker container?

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile, microservices

I am docker file like this:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:jre8 
ADD service-god-sac-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar 
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xmx64m", "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64m", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

When I compile and deploy the app settint the time using this:

> -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

I notice that the host time and containter time are syncronized, but the logs of the app shows a diferent time, the UTC time.
How can I sync the host machine, the container and the java app with the same time?

Comment: You may be interested in this discussion: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3359

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapping localtime and timezone works perfectly.

Example:

> docker run -d -v /var/lib/elasticsearch:/var/lib/elasticsearch -v
>   /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v
>   /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Buenos_Aires:/etc/timezone:ro -p 80:80/tcp
>   -p 9200:9200/tcp -p 514:514/udp petergrace/elk